Possible Telekinetic Powers
In my story a group of scientists are hired to perform an autopsy on a human who has telekinetic powers.
Upon autopsy, they find that the individual’s powers come from his ability to manipulate “and create” electromagnetic fields thanks to his altered muscles.
The scientists analyze his muscles to find that they are coated in a type of gel that’s similar to the gel found on the muscles of a Japanese Sleeper Ray. This gel is conductive and could be used to create electric fields.
At the end of the autopsy the scientists are left wondering how is this even possible so I’m here to ask. Is something like in my story possible “whether naturally occurring or man made”. Could someone have their muscles altered to produce electromagnetic fields?

If you are a human, or any kind of animal, then your muscles do indeed produce an electromagnetic field when working. See electromyography for how this is measured and used as a medical diagnostic tool. The real question would be if one could design a muscle which does not produce an electromagnetic field when working.

Please do basic research. To create an EM field you just need a moving charge. Cellular ion pumps are a thing (moving charge, build up of charge). All cells have ion pumps. That is all cells produce EM fields  Not particularly strong though. Muscles being coordinated in large groups make those signals detectable as AlexP mentions.

No, it is not possible. But you could leave the question open.

"Is this possible" is a terrible question to ask here. It may seem trite, but it's your world and anything is possible. Is it possible in the Real World? No. Of course not. And if humanity could synthesize the solution whomever knew how to do it would be running to the patent office, not talking about it here. You have a great idea for your story! It's a wonderful worldbuilding construct. It's exactly the kind of answer we would have given you if you'd asked for worldbuilding help rationalizing the effect. Cheers! Now go write your story.

Not the Way You Want
Electric organs (eg. in sharks, eels, rays) don't produce a continuous current of the sort required to generate an electromagnetic field meant to do work.  They generate short, intense voltage differences meant to stun prey or dissuade predators.  You're not going to be able to lift anything with that.
There's also a different problem: for an electric current to create a useful magnetic field, the current needs to to run through a lengthy conductor.  While blood can serve as a conductor, it's not a very good one, so if we're talking manmade, someone would have to embed coils of wire in the "telekinetic"'s body.
Beyond that, magnetic levitation (see also, everything Magneto does) requires either a tether or an induced current and a changing magnetic field.  Electric organs create DC current, not AC.  So you have a taser, not an electromagnet.
All of this combines to make someone with these organs being mistaken for a telekinetic basically impossible.

Not without costly external materials.
Biological materials aren't well suited to holding a massive moving charges. Fish use up most of their bodies to make shocks and it's mostly a slow build up to make a single large shock. Electromagnets which can do useful stuff like rip people's watches off require massive machines and metals and lots of power and other extremely magnetic materials.
Human bodies aren't suited for that. You could with extreme engineering get something that could do stuff like pull a coin from a short distance away, but it would be less effective than just palming a neodymium magnet.
